# Why does the function not save the parameter values to the datastructure?

Tags: c, pointers

I have a a datastructure

```
#ifndef DATASTRUCTURE_H
#define DATASTRUCTURE_H

#define MAXAPPOINTMENTS 100

typedef enum {So, Mo, Di, Mi, Do, Fr, Sa} eDayofTheWeek;

typedef struct{
    int Day;
    int Month;
    int Year;
    eDayofTheWeek WeekDay;
} sDate;

typedef struct{
    int Hour;
    int Minute;
    int Second;
}sTime;

typedef struct sALE{
    sDate Date;
    sTime Time;
    char *Description;
    char *Location;
    sTime Lenght;
    struct sALE *Next;
    struct sALE *Prev;
}sAppointment;

extern sAppointment *First, *Last, *Calendar;

#endif
```

which will be used in the function

```
void createAppointment(){
    int check = 0;

    sAppointment *Create = malloc(sizeof(sAppointment));
    if(Create != NULL){
        enter(1);
        printf("Termin erstellen");
        enter(2);
        if(getDate("Datum: ", &(Create->Date))){
            if(getTime("Uhrzeit[Std:Min]: ", &(Create->Time))){
                if(getDuration("Dauer[Std:Min:Sek]: ", &Create->Lenght)){
                    if(getText("Terminbeschreibung: ", 100, &Create->Description, 0)){
                        if(getText("Ort: ", 15, &Create->Location, 1))
                            check = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        enter(1);
    
        if(check == 1){
            insertInDList(Create, sort_DateTime);
            check = saveCalendar();
            if(check == 1){
                waitForEnter("Termin wurde erstellt\n\nDruecken Sie die Eingabetaste...");
            }
            else{
                printf("Speichern fehlgeschlagen. Mit einem Upgrade auf iCloud+ erhalten Sie auf diverse Geraete mehr Speicher und zusaetzliche Funktionen, wie 'iCloud Privat-Relay', 'E-Mail Adresse verbergen' und 'HomeKit Secure Video'.\nSie koennen sogar ihr Abo mit Ihrer Familie teilen. Weitere Infos finden Sie auf apple.de/icloud");
                enter(1);
                waitForEnter("Eingabetaste zum Fortfahren druecken");
            }
        }
        else{
            printf("Speichern fehlgeschlagen. Mit einem Upgrade auf iCloud+ erhalten Sie auf diverse Geraete mehr Speicher und zusaetzliche Funktionen, wie 'iCloud Privat-Relay', 'E-Mail Adresse verbergen' und 'HomeKit Secure Video'.\nSie koennen sogar ihr Abo mit Ihrer Familie teilen. Weitere Infos finden Sie auf apple.de/icloud");
            enter(1);
            waitForEnter("Eingabetaste zum Fortfahren druecken..");
        }
        free(Create);
    }
    else{
        printf("Speichern nicht moeglich. Mit einem Upgrade auf iCloud+ erhalten Sie auf diverse Geraete mehr Speicher und zusaetzliche Funktionen, wie 'iCloud Privat-Relay', 'E-Mail Adresse verbergen' und 'HomeKit Secure Video'.\nSie koennen sogar ihr Abo mit Ihrer Familie teilen. Weitere Infos finden Sie auf apple.de/icloud");
            enter(1);
            waitForEnter("Eingabetaste zum Fortfahren druecken..");
    }
}
```

The focus lays on getDate since there the values will not be saved in the Create-Datastructure(createAppointment).

getDate and it´s other functions:

```
int dayOfWeek(sDate *date){
    static int jMonth[] = {0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4};
    int d = date->Day;
    int m = date->Month;
    int y = date->Year;

    if(m < 3) y--;

    return(y + (y/4) - (y/100) + (y/400) + jMonth[m - 1] + d) % 7;
}


int isLeapYear(int year){
    return (((year % 4 == 0) &&  (year % 100 != 0)) || ((year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 == 0)));
}


int isDateValid(sDate *Date){
    int isDay;

    switch(Date->Month){
        case 1: isDay = 31; break;
        case 2: if(isLeapYear(Date->Year) == 1) isDay = 29; else isDay = 28; break;
        case 3: isDay = 31; break;
        case 4: isDay = 30; break;
        case 5: isDay = 31; break;
        case 6: isDay = 30; break;
        case 7: isDay = 31; break;
        case 8: isDay = 31; break;
        case 9: isDay = 30; break;
        case 10: isDay = 31; break;
        case 11: isDay = 30; break;
        case 12: isDay = 31;break;
        default: isDay = 0;
    }
    if(((Date->Day < 1) || (Date->Day > isDay) || (Date->Year < 1)) == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    else return 0;
}



int getDateFromString(char *in, sDate *dateptr){                            
    int counter = 0;                                                        
    int j = 0;                                                              
    char point = '.';                                                       
    char read[20];                                                        
                                                                            
    for(int i = 0;counter<3;i++){                                           
        if(in[i] == point || in[i] == NULL){               
            if(counter == 0) dateptr->Day = atoi(read);
            else if(counter == 1) dateptr->Month = atoi(read);
            else if(counter == 2) dateptr->Year = atoi(read);

            counter++;
            j = 0;
        }
        else{
            read[j] = in[i];
            read[j+1] = '\0';
            j++;
        }

        if(in[i] == NULL){
            if(isDateValid(dateptr)){
                dateptr->WeekDay = dayOfWeek(dateptr);
                return 1;
            }
            else return 0;
        }
    }
}



int getDate(char *prompt, sDate *date){
    char in[20];

    date = malloc(sizeof(sDate));
    
    do{
        printf(prompt);
        scanf("%s", in);
        clearBuffer();
    }while(getDateFromString(in, date) != 1); //getDateFromString is parsing 'in' which should be a date in german format(00.00.0000) into day, month and year and give the values to the 'date'-datastructure

    if(date != NULL){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        printf("Kein Speicher vorhanden. Mit einem Upgrade auf iCloud+ erhalten Sie auf diverse Geraete mehr Speicher und zusaetzliche Funktionen, wie 'iCloud Privat-Relay', 'E-Mail Adresse verbergen' und 'HomeKit Secure Video'. Sie koennen sogar ihr Abo mit Ihrer Familie teilen. Weitere Infos finden Sie auf apple.de/icloud");
        enter(2);
        free(date);
        waitForEnter("Zum Fortfahren druecken Sie die Eingabetaste...");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

getDate will malloc the date-pointer in the functionparameter and ask the user for a date input(german format) and then parses the input in getDateFromString, giving the values in the datastructure.

As watching in the Debugger I saw that it all works and *date will indeed have the values I wanted. But since *date is a function-parameter and I set Create->Date in the createAppointment function I expectet it to have the values of *date but the debugger shows otherwise. It shows me more a sort of random numbers instead while Create->Description and Create->Location are fine.

Why is that happening?

Comment: `date` is passed by value. The new `date` value assigned from `malloc` will not be seen by the caller.

Comment: @Angargedon Please provide a minimal complete program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @WeijunZhou Where is there date passed by value?

Comment: It is the correct time to learn how to use the ***debugger***

Comment: `getDate("Datum: ", &(Create->Date))`. I mean the pointer `date` itself is passed by value (as is everything else in C), so reassigning `date` in the function body is always wrong as the new value will not be seen by the caller.

Comment: As `getDate()` is being used in the code presented, there seems to be no reason for it to allocate memory for a date anyway.  It is being passed a pointer to an existing `sDate` object, so it already has that pointed-to object to write a date into.  The dynamically allocated object serves no useful purpose there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You called `getDate("Datum: ", &(Create->Date))` and expect that the `getDate` function will allocate the memory for the `sDate` struct. Let's take a look at the `getDate` function and see why it cannot possibly do so,

```
int getDate(char *prompt, sDate *date){
    char in[20];
    date = malloc(sizeof(sDate));
    //some code manipulating date
}
```

As `date` the pointer itself is passed by value as everything else in C, **any** update to its value cannot be seen by the caller. In this particular case, `date = malloc(sizeof(sDate))` allocates a new block of memory and the beginning of the block is assigned to `date`, and your later code in the same function all uses `date` and manipulate on the new block, that's why everything appears fine within the function. However, once you leave this function, the allocated block is leaked and you can't refer to the block any longer.

Since you reassigned `date`, you are not operating on `Create->Date` at all. Rule of thumb, reassignments to function parameters only have local effect in C.

In this case, the fix is simple. Since `Date` is a member of `Create`. You **already allocated** the memory required for `Date` when you allocate for `Create`, so just remove the line `date = malloc(sizeof(sDate));` and you'll directly operate on `Create->Date`.

You then no longer need to check whether `date` is `NULL` and of course don't need the `free` either.